# JavaFX, Stacked Bar Charts and CSS

Tags: java, css, charts, javafx-2

I've been using JavaFX now for a few months and have a question regarding CSS and Charts.  I have a stacked bar chart and I have several series I use - lets say they're series A, B, C, D and E.  When I generate the chart not all of the series will be in the chart, for example some charts may have A, B and C, others will have just B and E where another could have all 5.  Basically I am programmatically generating the series based upon the dataset I am working with.

So in this case I want the color of the series to be the same on each chart.  When I generate these, if I only have B and E the css class names that reflect the colors of these are:

.default-color0.chart-bar and .default-color1.chart-bar - and here these simply set the color of the series order - so series 1 will get the "..color0.chart.." definition, series 2 "..color1.chart.." etc.  And when I don't know before I process the data which one will be first I will need to set these dynamically in the code.

The only solution I've found for this is to set the stylesheet of the stacked bar chart to a CSS file I created pre-compile.  And this works well, and below is an example of how I would do this in code.

```
myStackedBarChart.getStylesheets().add("/myapp/chartSeriesColors.css");
```

The only problem is because a series in position 1 is not known, I would have to create CSS files of each permutation of possible series and I know this is a bad solution.

I've looked everywhere on a way to set the series CSS dynamically at run-time but have not found this - is there way to do this.  Basically wanting to set the following CSS class definitions as so:

```
.default-color0.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: #<a color I would set at runtime>; }
.default-color1.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: #<a color I would set at runtime>; }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the chart has been shown on the Stage:

```
for (Node n: chart.lookupAll(".default-color0.chart-bar")) n.setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: azure;");
```

Comment: Thank you SO much jewelsea - I even tried this method above before without luck (sorry for not writing that now that I think about it).  But the key to your post was where you wrote "*After* the chart has been shown on the Stage:" - that was it.  My code before was looking for this before it was rendered on the stage.  Thank you again so much.

Comment: I have another question jewelsea - is there a way to programatically determine when a chart has been shown on the Stage?  For the stacked bar chart this is working well, but I have another situation with piecharts that isn't working because it's executing before the pie chart is rendered/shown on the stage.

Comment: Good question - ask it on StackOverflow or the Oracle JavaFX forum.  I don't know the answer.  In the past I have used a Timeline to delay processing until a node was probably displayed (see [a sample](https://gist.github.com/2129306)).

Comment: Thank you again -I have searched the API for any event I could use but didn't find one.  Here is what I did learn here.